# Add, update and query SharePoint list items from CSOM using javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, addition

Using javascript and SharePoint's CSOM, can someone provide an example for the follow scenario:

Get field value from the selected items in a list (ListA).

Then for each item selected, take a fields value and use it to query a different list (ListB).

If the query returns 0 rows, create item in ListB and update selected item in ListA.

Else if the query returns 1 row, update selected item in ListA.

Answer (score 3):

This will get you started.

[MSDN - How to: Complete basic operations using JavaScript library code in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163201.aspx)

It gives examples of how to

- Query lists and get value
- Add/update and delete records
- and many others common operations

So, most of what you need to complete your scenario.